# Dúvida na utilização do LEFT JOIN no mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho duas tabelas. alunos e prova

alunos tem 10 alunos
provas tem 9 resultados (pois um aluno faltou)

A união das tabelas se dá pelo campo matricula.

Quero unir as duas tabelas e exibir todos os alunos (inclusive o que faltou).
Em pesquisas vi que se usasse o LEFT JOIN conseguiria.

Estou conseguindo exibir. Só que o aluno que faltou não sai na exibição.

Minha consulta está assim:

```
SELECT alunos.*, provas.* FROM alunos 
LEFT JOIN provas ON alunos.matricula = provas.aluno_matricula 
WHERE provas.cod_prova = '00112233'
ORDER BY alunos.nome ASC
```

Este tipo de consulta estaria de acordo para exibir o nome do aluno que tem na tabela alunos e não tem na tabela notas?

Obrigado!

Comment: O que é o cod_prova?

Answer (score 3):

Para este caso, você irá retornar todos os registros da tabela de alunos, mesmo que não estejam na tabela de provas, porém como você está filtrando dados da tabela de provas, você deveria considerar também o valor nulo, pois quando não existir nenhum registro correspondente, o valor será nulo, por exemplo:

```sql
SELECT alunos.*, provas.* FROM alunos 
LEFT JOIN provas ON alunos.matricula = provas.aluno_matricula 
WHERE provas.cod_prova = '00112233' or provas.cod_prova is null
ORDER BY alunos.nome ASC
```

Fazendo desta maneira, mesmo que não existam registros correspondentes na tabela de provas, irá trazer.

Comment: Mateus. Primeiramente obrigado! Fiz como descreveu e trouxe os alunos que fizeram provas de outro código.

Comment: Poderia editar sua pergunta e colocar a estrutura e os dados das tabelas?